# Websockets vs Sockets to transfer files between Android mobile application to Windows machine using Python

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I want to send files from a Android application to Windows machine (Desktop application should be developed using Python) which will act as a server. Which will be the most preferable one between [Websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) and [Sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html).

Comment: I would suggest using neither of those and instead use python http server on windows machine.It is very simple but more than enough to transfer files.

Comment: But it has basic security right? Their site does not recommend it too for production.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Comment: for production use flask with enabled https